# remove the dat tag from a track on google earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have written a kml file for displaying a track on Google earth. This track shows a radio wave on Google earth. In every track on Google earth is a constant tag like : "2009-08-17T23:40:29Z" which move along the icon during the track, now i really do need to hide this tag, is there any way to do this? Here is my code and a image showing the part that i need to remove.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Catalina - gx:Track</name>
<LookAt>
<gx:TimeSpan>
<begin>2014-08-17T23:22:32Z</begin>
<end>2014-08-17T23:23:32Z</end>
</gx:TimeSpan>
<longitude>51.4231</longitude>
<latitude>35.6930</latitude>
<altitude>0</altitude>
<heading>0</heading>
<tilt>0</tilt>
<range>950683.078661</range>
</LookAt>



<StyleMap id="multiTrack">
<Pair>
<key>normal</key>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack_n</styleUrl>
</Pair>
<Pair>
<key>highlight</key>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack_h</styleUrl>
</Pair>
</StyleMap>
<Style id="multiTrack_n">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wireless/512/22-512.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>99ffac59</color>
<width>6</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="multiTrack_h">
<IconStyle>
<scale>1.2</scale>
<Icon>
<href></href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>99ffac59</color>
<width>8</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>2009-08-13T17:35:24Z</name>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack</styleUrl>
<gx:Track>
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
<when>2009-08-17T23:22:32Z</when>
<when>2009-08-17T23:40:29Z</when>

<gx:coord>53.2203,29.2736</gx:coord>
<gx:coord>53.9667,26.5333,0</gx:coord>
</gx:Track>
</Placemark>
 <Placemark>

    <gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>56.1212,36.0114,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you remain the track name empty this constant part will vanish, the default name is something like this in track block:

```
<name>2009-08-13T17:35:24Z</name>
```

you can remain this empty, simply like this:

```
<name></name>
```

with no harm. ;)